# Assets API : how to fetch data from different response pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, content-builder

I always get the same data set when using below (tested with different "page" values):

```
 path: '/asset/v1/content/assets/query'
 method: 'POST'
```

Payload

```
"query": {
  "property": "assetType.name",
  "simpleOperator": "equal",
  "value": "Template",
},
"page": {
  "page": 2,
  "pageSize": 50
}
```

What should be done to get the data from page 2 for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through different pages by supplying a different page number in the page.page property. If the page number exceeds the actual number of pages, you'll receive an empty items array.

For page 1 with a maximum of 50 items:

```
{
    "query": {
        "property": "assetType.name",
        "simpleOperator": "equal",
        "value": "Template",
    },
    "page": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 50
    }
}
```

For page 2 with a maximum of 50 items:

```
{
    "query": {
        "property": "assetType.name",
        "simpleOperator": "equal",
        "value": "Template",
    },
    "page": {
        "page": 2,
        "pageSize": 50
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work out for you, try using a different or no filter (remove the query-property). Also check the "count" returned in the response payload. Additionally add your response payload (with sensitive data and irrelevant properties removed) to your question.

Comment: I did a bit of trial and error and it worked for me in the end. This is what I am getting now for page: 3 => {"count":0,"page":0,"pageSize":0,"links":{},"items":[]} - which is the result I wanted to achieve.